# NonlinearModelFit of data with errors

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, around

Experimental data points **invariably** come with errors. These errors can significantly influence the parameters and their uncertainties when performing non-linear fitting. However, NonlinearModelFit seems does not natively support fitting data with errors specified using the Around function. Did I miss something? Is there a specific parameter I should enable for this purpose? Alternatively, should I consider a different function? It's surprising that this function seems more suited for educational demonstrations and theoretical exercises than for practical, real-world data fitting.

Comment: You did not explain, what fails you among the instruments of the NonlinearModelFit.

Comment: Have a look at my resource function [FitWithErrors](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FitWithErrors/). It's a wrapper that sits on top of the Weights option of `NonlinearModelFit`

Comment: I think the bigger issue that that the native regression functions only allow one source of error.  (*Mathematica* certainly has the capability to analyze models with multiple sources of error - mixed models - but one has to program from scratch to do so.)  Your example likely has at least two sources of error:  the measurement error and the lack-of-fit error.  And my certainly biased view is that many times the source of `Around` values are simply the square root of a count or a "believed percent std. error" which makes untested (and unexamined) assumptions.